# How to work with date type input to match both JSON format and date format in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json, date

I have RESTfull service that produces and consumes JSON object

```
{
firstName: "Alex",
lastName: "Ross",
studentGroup: {
groupId: 1,
groupName: "java 15-1"
},
admissionDate: "2015-03-25",
status: {
statusId: 3,
statusName: "expelled"
},
term: {
termId: 4,
termName: "fourth"
},
id: 1
}
```

Here is **admissionDate** field which coresponds to input with type="date" on html page (page services to update object... so it should display current value and commit new one from date picker to RESTfull service):

```
<input required type="date" ng-model="student.admissionDate">
```

So, before representation of current value I converted its String value to date:

```
$scope.student.admissionDate = new Date(student.admissionDate);
```

Input produces date like - '*Fri Mar 11 2016 14:36:29 GMT+0200 (FLE Standard Time)*'. **BUT** service doesn't recognize this format, expected is '*yyyy-MM-dd*' format.
To avoid errors I use angular filter like

```
student.admissionDate = $filter('date')($scope.student.admissionDate, "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Object can be send to server as well (`PUT: /student`) but in Chrome developer console I can observe error - "`[ngModel:datefmt]`" because the value format has been changed in `<input>` tag.

[image: Chrome console with Angular validation error]

How can I solve this problem? What changes should be made to suit both Server format (`'yyy-MM-dd'`) and angular validation in `<input type="date">`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bPReYzwR062iLPRnAz3x?p=preview

Here are my files (but without Services side... not sure how to share it here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the value you are passing to the `filter` is a string. You need to do `new Date('the_date_string')` before passing it to the filter.

That might work.

Comment: Yes, I did this... but not share 
$scope.student.admissionDate = new Date(student.admissionDate);
The problem is - AngularJS does 'ng-date' validation after date transformations and throws error.

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle of your code? That would be more helpful in debugging.

Comment: You can use the Date constructor to parse the string if you happy for browsers to randomly parse it as UTC, local or NaN. Manually parse the string.

Comment: @RobG , sorry.. didn't get you